# SSRS How to see multi value parameter in subscription

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I tried to get value from query or to specify values, as soon as the parameter is multi value i can't see the data when i'm trying to make my subscription.
my request looks like :

```
select id from employee where canal in(@canal)
```

[image]

what should i do, i'm totally stuck,
when i did research i saw data driven subscription but i don't have access to it apparently, don't know if that help

Comment: Did my answer help you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by saying sorry this isn't a pleasant answer. You've run into a limitation with the built-in functionality. Thankfully there are workarounds.

The problem is that you can only pass 1 value into the data-driven subscription. So you have use a comma-separated list and get the query/report to parse out the values.

1. If you have or can create a `Split` function in your database, that is a good option. This would be a table-valued user defined function and there are some easy to find examples already. Also this function is generally good to have for other use cases anyway. With this your SQL would read:

   where canal in Split(@canal)
2. SSRS works really well with SQL Server, but when you use an ODBC connection, the parameter support is limited. You can use the same multi-value parameter workaround that is required in those cases.

   - In the Dataset properties > parameters tab, use an expression like this to combine the values into a single comma-separated string surrounded by commas.

   ="," + Join(Parameters!canal.Value, ",") + ","

   - The SQL would look like this:

   where @ like '%,' + canal + ',%'

Basically, this searches row-by-row for values that are contained in the string.

In either case, the query in your data-driven subscription settings will need to return the comma-separated string. Then you can select that column in the report parameters value field. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Steven , i will try that asap .